# Recursive directory iterator lists dots, but not directories?

Tags: php, iterator, filesystems

This line should list all files and subdirectories of `$absPath`:

```
$iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($absPath,
 \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST | \FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
```

But I only get files!

If I remove the `\FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS` flag then I get subdirectories too, but with dots appended, eg:

```
[0] => abc/.
[1] => abc/..
[2] => abc/def/.
[3] => abc/def/..
```

Does anyone have a clue why this is happening?

Comment: Not sure, but I think `\RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST` should be a flag for `\RecursiveIteratorIterator`, not `\RecursiveDirectoryIterator`

Comment: yep that was the reason, thanks! man I need another coffee..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a flag for `RecursiveIteratorIterator` in the arguments of `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`.

```
$iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($absPath,
 \FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
```